# need to display fields that has same name but different value when join in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I need to join two tables but both the table has a field named 'username' both the table has different values i, i need to display both values in the field 'username' how it possible in codeigniter

```
public function tech_work_completed($id) {
    $this->db->select('c.username,u.id,tw.*,w.*');
    $this->db->from('tbl_tech_work tw');
    $this->db->join('tbl_customers c', 'tw.user_id = c.id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('tbl_users u', 'u.id = tw.technician_id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('tbl_works w', 'w.user_id = c.id', 'left');
    $this->db->where('w.wrk_status', 'completed');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

this is my model , both table `tbl_customer` and `tbl_users` contain a field name username so when display username it get from `tbl_user`. I need from `tbl_customers`

Comment: Can you show us the contents of `$query->result()`? It'll be easier to visualise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use column aliasing at the time of column selection like:

```
t1.username as uname1, t2.username as uname2
```

By using this you will two column with name uname1, uname2

or

```
$this->db->select('course_name AS `Course Name`, course_desc AS `Course Description`, display_public AS `Display Status`', FALSE);
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Mayank Pandeyz's answer:

Since you want to display both values in the field 'username', along with the alias, you can use CONCAT.

After you've set the aliases `t1.username as uname1, t2.username as uname2` as Mayank Pandeyz described, you can "make" the field username like so:

```
concat( t1.username, " ",t2.username ) AS username
```

This will create new column in the result, called as you want (in this case "username"). It will contain both values, separated by whitespace (separator is chosen by us).